# How to detect youtube traffic?

Tags: networking

I want to block all traffic to and from Youtube on my router.

Unfortunately, as Google is using a reverse proxy, youtube.com and google.com have the same IP.
As the communication is in HTTPS, ie on TLS session, it's impossible to know the hostname.

Do you see any trick to detect Youtube traffic ? I thought about DPI with nDPI but it's not very scalable.

Comment: what router are you using? you could use rules to handle outbound query dns to not resolve youtube.

Comment: DNS blocking is not reliable, the user could use the IP directly ...

Answer (score 1):

> As the communication is in HTTPS, ie on TLS session, it's impossible to know the hostname.

TLS client hello usually includes the hostname in cleartext, for [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Here are a couple of examples sent by Firefox and captured with Wireshark:

[image: SNI inspected with Wireshark]

Not sure if this counts as DPI for your purposes. Also, I think there’s [work underway](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-sni-encryption) on making this SNI information encrypted as well, so not sure for how long this approach will be viable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the wireshark test, I didn't know SNI was in plain text. However it seems it's only passed during the Hello message, and never again (I checked on wireshark too). It looks like a DNS blocking then, which is not really reliable ...

Comment: Nope, if you enter IP of Youtube in browser, opens google.com page. Because server can't understand which site you trying access by common IP.

Answer (score 0):

May be enough to limit speed to google subnet. 
So reading search result text would be OK, but video from youtube would very slow loading.
Google disk downloads also would slow.

As marked in other comment in Hello packet is clear text address. 
So if you can detect connection by SNI, you can mark connection in iptables and apply some rules for this connection.